# display byte array as pdf in browser i tried several options from stack overflow but it did not work for me

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser, byte

> I am getting following response which is in json format

### {"filename":"copyofabc.pdf","filedata":[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,53,13,10,37,-75,-75,-75,-75,13,10,49,32,48,32,111,98,106,13,10,60,60,47,84,121,112,101,47,67,97,116,97,108,111,103,47,80,97,103,101,115,32,50,32,48,32,82,47,76,97,110,103,40,101,110,45,73,78,41,32,47,83,116,114,117,99,116,84,114,101,101,82,111,111,11.....]}

```
enter code here


 var blob = new Blob($(this).attr('filedata'), {
                        type: 'application/pdf'
                    });
                    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    // Create an iframe to demonstrate it:
                    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                    iframe.className = 'sample-iframe';
                    iframe.src = objectURL;
                    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

> above code i am using to display pdf from byte array

Comment: Please post example if you have

Answer (score 6):

This works for me on Chrome, but not on IE:

```
// base64DataFromWebAPI comes from a Web API, in the form of base 64 string
var pdfData = base64DataFromWebAPI;

var x = window.open();
var iframe = x.document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.width = '100%'
iframe.height = '100%'
iframe.frameBorder = 0
iframe.style = "border: 0"
iframe.src = "data:application/pdf;base64, " + pdfData
x.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

I got it from the following Stack Oveflow question: [JsPDF - Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493234/jspdf-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url)

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome*, you can also simply paste the following code in the address bar:

```
data:application/pdf;base64, YOUR_PDF_DATA_HERE
```

It will open it in the included PDF viewer of the browser.

*didn't tested other browsers