# JsPDF - Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL

Tags: google-chrome, frame, jspdf

After updating Google Chrome, the report jsPDF in a new Window does not work any more.

The console shows the message:

> Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL:
>   data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1....

Can you help-me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This works well now that chrome has removed top frame navigation. Only downloading the pdf in chrome gives problem. Download works in well in firefox tho.

```
var string = doc.output('datauristring');
var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + string + "'></iframe>"
var x = window.open();
x.document.open();
x.document.write(iframe);
x.document.close();
```

Comment: This solution worked for me very well.  I'm using html2canvas.

Comment: Worked for me on Firefox and Chrome. Needed to  encodeURIComponent(string) though.

Comment: Then what is the solution for downloading in Chrome?

Comment: Not sure yet. I'll post the solution if I find any @SukantaBala If someone finds any then please post. I'll upvote it.

Comment: @SukantaBala As of now this is how I have handled the download issue. 
                                                                                         
 doc.save(filename + '.pdf');                                                                        This code automatically downloads the pdf without having to click the download button.

Comment: It's important to use the 'datauristring' option, other options, although may return a datauri, will also open windows and may cause console errors, works well though.

Comment: @Joyston do you call this as well as open the PDF in an iframe?

Comment: Yes @NorCalKnockOut. Atleast for my purpose I needed to view the pdf so I had to open it in an iframe. You could directly save on your local machine as well by using doc.save(filename + '.pdf');

Comment: @Joyston Did you ever find a solution for fixing the download button in Chrome?

Comment: using this method, little download icon doesnt work, user can only see the document and cannot save it, anyone else facing the same?

Comment: You should also set `frameborder` to 0 and `style` to `margin: 0`.

Comment: Also, this solution has the url in the url box on `about:blank`. Is there a way to change the url to the data url, possibly without navigating?

Answer (score 40):

Apparently Google Chrome has removed support for top-frame navigation, you can see more informations here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM

You may try to render the jsPDF to an iFrame

Comment: hi @MárcioRossato can you please send me the code to render jsPdf in the i frame.

Comment: @KuldeePChoudharY hi, i'm using angularJS, I sent the script, and I hope help-you !!

Comment: Can't download the pdf using this way the download button is not working.

Comment: @MárcioRossato Can you post the script as new answer

Comment: hi @Pruthviraj,  after I use de object tag, like this: 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649105/not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url-jspdf/45684345#45684345

Answer (score 19):

I recently had the same problem using FileReader object to read content and show my JSReport.

```
 var reader = new FileReader();                        
 reader.onload = function (e) {
      window.open(reader.result, "_blank");
 }
 reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Unfortunatly after chrome update all my report stopped working.
I tried to fix this by using Blob object and it's still working but if you have a popup blocker it will not work.

```
 var file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/pdf' });
 var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
 window.open(fileURL);
```

I finally find a way to avoid this problem by creating the iFrame dynamically after reading this topic and i decided to share the **solution**.

```
 var file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'application/pdf' });
 var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
 var win = window.open();
 win.document.write('<iframe src="' + fileURL + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

Comment: Works for displaying and printing but can't download the pdf, the download button seems to be not triggered.

Comment: Download works in FF but not in Chrome. Anyone found a solution for chrome yet?

Comment: I didn't find a way to fix this but you can temporary add a download button before your iFrame:
'<a href="' + fileURL + '" download="DownloadPDF">Download PDF<\a>'

This will not affect the print button as long as it is not in the iFrame.
You can also ask the user if he wants to download or view the file on main event.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But his doesn't seem to be working in edge browser, Any suggestions?

Comment: The solution works very well but it can be blocked by the popup blocker. Is there a way to prevent this ?
My goal was to use this to replace the classic file download. I don't want to show the file link so I've replaced it by an authentified POST call that returns the binary.
Thank you.

Comment: Seems like it only works with pdf but I want to use it for my text data.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe can help, create a function to export with the download attribute html5:

```
var docPdf = doc.output();
exportToFile(docPdf,defaults.type);

function exportToFile(data,type){

    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/'+type+';filename='+'exportar.'+type+';'+'charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'exportar.'+type;
    hiddenElement.click();
}
```

Comment: such approach can cause browser to freeze the whole page for some time

Comment: Still throws the error, even when the user clicks it

Answer (score 6):

the `download` property of the `a` element has to contain a file name.

```
function window_download( datauri )
{
  const match = datauri.match(/(filename=)([^;]+)/);
  const fileName = match ? match[2] : '' ;
  if ( fileName )
  {
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = datauri ;
    downloadLink.click();
  }
else
{
throw 'missing download file name' ;
}
```

```
   // get contents of pdf from jsPDF as a data uri.
    const uri = pdf.output('datauristring', 'packing-list.pdf' );
    window_download( uri ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var pdfUrl = doc.output('datauri').substring(doc.output('datauri').indexOf(',')+1);
var binary = atob(pdfUrl.replace(/\s/g, ''));
var len = binary.length;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
}

var blob = new Blob( [view], { type: "application/pdf" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

function openPDF(){
    window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this solves the original question?

Comment: you can use this code to open the pdf document in a new tab as a blob... cause chrome blocks JsPDF from opening the document.... which i believe is the original question.

Answer (score 3):

As chrome removed its support for - Top-frame navigation. Luckily jsPDF has an API - "save()", which offers the same functionality as  `doc.output('datauri')`

Below is the example implementation of save()

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 300, 160);    
doc.save('fileName.pdf');
```

save(filename, options) → {jsPDF|Promise}

Saves as PDF document. An alias of jsPDF.output('save', 'filename.pdf'). Uses FileSaver.js-method saveAs.
Refer [JSPDF documentation](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#save) for more information -

Comment: best and easiest answer . should be the highest votes . thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Add attrbute download

```
<a href="data:image/jpg;base64,/AA/AABBCCDD..." download="name.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<iframe id="ManualFrame"
        frameborder="0"
        style="border:0"
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

<script>
    $(function () {
        setManualFrame();
    });

    function setManualFrame() {
        $("#ManualFrame").attr("height", screen.height);
        $("#ManualFrame").attr("width", screen.width);
        $("#ManualFrame").attr("src", "data:application/pdf;base64," + Your_PDF_Data);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Joyston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5911998/joyston)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45789588), but without reparsing and therefore without additional need to escape something:

```
x=window.open();
iframe=x.document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.width='100%'
iframe.height='100%'
iframe.frameBorder=0
iframe.style="border: 0"
iframe.src='data:text/html........' //data-uri content here
x.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: I don’t know why, but by using x=window.open(‘about:whatever’); seems to enable downloading.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Creates an anchor element `<a></a>` with
 * the base64 pdf source and a filename with the
 * HTML5 `download` attribute then clicks on it.
 * @param  {string} pdf 
 * @return {void}     
 */
function downloadPDF(pdf) {
    const linkSource = `data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}`;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    const fileName = "vct_illustration.pdf";

    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

Source from: https://medium.com/octopus-labs-london/downloading-a-base-64-pdf-from-an-api-request-in-javascript-6b4c603515eb

Answer (score 0):

@kuldeep-choudhary

Hi, in fact, to solve i'm using object tag with angularJS 1.5.xx

```
<object ng-attr-data="{{data}}" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

and in script:

```
$scope.doc.data = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(doc.output("datauristring"));
```

---

In pure javascript, maybe like this works:

html:

```
<object id="obj" type="application/pdf" ></object>
```

js:

```
document.elementById('obj').data = doc.output("datauristring");
```

please, try and correct-me if I wrong.

Comment: I can't use AngularJS, can you please send it in JavaScript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649105/not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url-jspdf

Answer (score 0):

Not related to jspdf, but did help me here (and this question is the top hit at google): If specifying a `download="..."` attribute to the anchor tag, the download prompt will properly open up.

Answer (score 0):

Using  download=""  made me able to download the file

Answer (score 0):

In angular2+ -

**app.component.html** -

```
 <object id="obj"  [attr.data]  type="application/pdf"> </object>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 document.getElementById('obj').dataset.data = doc.output("datauristring");

  var blob = doc.output("blob");
  window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```