# Window is not allowed to navigate Top-frame navigations to data URLs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, pdf-generation

Earlier following code would open a pdf file in a new window.

```
var pdfDocument = "data:application/pdf;base64," + data;
window.open(pdfDocument);
```

After updating chrome, it seems to stop working. Appranely, chrome removed Top-frame navigations to data URLs.

How can I solve my issue now? I need to open this pdf in a new window. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Solved it using iFrame. Thanks to [Pedro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45495974/1987020) for giving me the idea.

```
<iframe id="ManualFrame"
        frameborder="0"
        style="border:0"
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

<script>
    $(function () {
        setManualFrame();
    });

    function setManualFrame() {
        $("#ManualFrame").attr("height", screen.height);
        $("#ManualFrame").attr("width", screen.width);
        $("#ManualFrame").attr("src", "data:application/pdf;base64," + '@ViewBag.pdf_base64_data');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you read this question from a couple of days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493234/jspdf-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url - oops, you posted an **ANSWER** there! That wont last long

Comment: By the way, this behaviour is coming to Firefox very soon too - so you'd better figure out how to use iframe's for this

Comment: I am not familiar with iFrame. Can you help on this regard?

Comment: Sure, MDN has documentation for all the elements, including [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: Thank you for this answer but can you tell me how I can download the pdf from the iframe? Is it possible?

Comment: @PallaviPrasad: If it's a pdf, it should already have download option. Look [here](http://imgur.com/a/MFfRl) for the idea.

Comment: @LonelyPlaneteer When I click on download it has no action here, you did something else to download? Found a question with same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775868/new-tab-with-pdf-download-button-not-working-on-chrome

Comment: @GustavoGraupner, I have not done anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Deprecations and Removals in Chrome 60:

> #### Remove content-initiated top frame navigations to data URLs
>
> Because of their unfamiliarity to non-technical browser users, we're increasingly seeing the data: scheme being used in spoofing and phishing attacks. To prevent this, we're **blocking** web pages from loading data: URLs in the top frame. This applies to  tags, window.open, window.location and similar mechanisms. The data: scheme will still work for resources loaded by a page.
>
> This feature was deprecated in Chrome 58 and is now removed.

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/chrome-60-deprecations

Comment: Hello, this seems more of a comment not an answer. And, the user seems to be aware of the reason that the issue happens.

Comment: the question it self also have answer with update but not detailed description of cause of issue. I only want to share description.

Comment: I understand, but a description of the issue is not an answer

Comment: Even a browser Ctrl-R refresh doesn't work. Had to a bug there.

Comment: Wish browser makers would enact policy: every new security restriction must be accompanied by a user-controlled override. Some of us want to use the browser as a portable O/S and not have to shove crap to the (hey look, less secure!) server just to work around however-well-intentioned security hobbles.