# New tab with PDF - Download button not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, download, base64

When user clicks on a button, I send a request to my server, and it sends back a pdf base64.

Then I open it in a new tab, but the download button from **Chrome** preview does not work, when I click it there is no action. It works fine on Firefox.

Chrome preview download button:

[image: Chrome preview download button]

Define variable `iframeHtml`:

```js
let iframeHtml = `<iframe
    id="ManualFrame"
    frameborder="0"
    style="border:0; overflow: hidden; margin: 0; height: 100%"
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>

<script>
setManualFrame();

function setManualFrame() {
  document.getElementById('ManualFrame').setAttribute('height', screen.height);
  document.getElementById('ManualFrame').setAttribute('width', screen.width);
  document.getElementById('ManualFrame').setAttribute('src', "data:application/pdf;base64,${pdfBase64}");
}
</script>`;
```

Then open it in a new tab:

```js
let newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.document.write(iframeHtml);
```

Chrome versions I've tested:
Version: **67.0.3396.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)**
Version: **66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) 32 bits**

Comment: Having same issue here

Comment: Which version of Chrome you are using?

Comment: @LonelyPlaneteer I've added the versions tested to the question

Comment: @JairoOdeliJunior: Interesting. I am using the same version. Same code. Can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59884015/chrome-pdf-viewer-download-button-doesnt-work-on-window-open-tab

The solution is to use `window.open('about:blank');` before writing the iFrame HTML.