# Chrome PDF viewer download button doesn't work on window.open() tab

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I'm working on a project, which sends http requests to the spring boot. As response I receive a stream with PDF file. I need to open this file in a new tab with all functionality of Chrome PDF viewer, especially downloading.

Here's my code of processing response and opening a new tab with received PDF file:

```
fetch(options.url, options)
        .then(response => {
            return response.blob();
        })
        .then(blob => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            reader.onload = () => {
                const data = reader.result
                const tab = window.open();
                tab.document.write("<html>" +
                                        "<body>" +
                                            "<embed type='application/pdf' " +
                                                    "style='position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;' " +
                                                    "width='100%' " +
                                                    "height='100%' " +
                                                    "src='" + data +"'/>" +
                                        "</body>" +
                                    "</html>")
            }
        })
```

But there is a problem after new tab opened: all buttons of Chrome PDF viewer work correctly except for 'download' button. 
[image]

Nothing happens after clicking the button.

Do you have an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `const tab = window.open();` with `const tab = window.open('about:blank', '_blank', "width=200,height=100");`

Answer (score 0):

I made a little change to [Tafadzwa Chimberengwa's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8336317/tafadzwa-chimberengwa)  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64051529) to open in full screen (edited):

```
window.open('about:blank', '_blank', 'width=100%, height=100%');
```