# Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The html file with text "Full Example code of Export table with Sorting, Searching and Paging(responsive) features" provided in the below link to export data table into different options.

http://technoscripts.com/export-html-table/
However all the export options doesn't work when tested locally and throws the following error on clicking export options for

file:///C:/Test/libs/tableExport.js:171 Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:application/json;filename=exportData;base64,W3siaGVhZGVyIjpbWyJTci5ObyIsIk5hbWUiLCJDb3VudHJ5IiwiU2FsYXJ5Il1dLCJkYXRhIjpbWyIwMDEiLCJSYWh1bCIsIkluZGlhIiwiMjAwMDAiXSxbIjAwMiIsIkNoYXJsZXMiLCJVbml0ZWQgS2luZ2RvbSIsIjI4MDAwIl0sWyIwMDMiLCJNZW5zaHJpbCIsIkF1c3RyYWxpYSIsIjcwMDAwIl0sWyIwMDQiLCJHYW5lc2giLCJJbmRpYSIsIjE4MDAwIl0sWyIwMDUiLCJNYWl0aGlsaSIsIkluZGlhIiwiMTIwMDAiXSxbIjAwNiIsIlBhdmFuIiwiSW5kaWEiLCI1MDAwMCJdLFsiMDA3IiwiUmFrZXNoIiwiVVMiLCI3NTAwMCJdLFsiMDA4IiwiTWF5dXIiLCJJbmRpYSIsIjEwMDAwMCJdLFsiMDA5IiwiTmlSUmFOamFuIiwiSW5kaWEiLCI4NTAwMCJdLFsiMDEwIiwiVGFubWF5IiwiQXVzdHJpYSIsIjMwMDAwIl1dfV0=
The following export options doesn't work

JSON, JSON (IgnoreColumn), JSON (With Escape), PNG, PDF

One more demo link http://demo.technoscripts.com/3/#

Please let me know.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493234/jspdf-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url