# In Chrome Signature-Pad save just opens blank page; works fine in other browsers

Tags: javascript

Chrome 60.0.3112.113 (64-bit)

macOS 10.12.6 (16G29)

Signature-Pad 2.3.0 Demo Page: (http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad)

Signature-Pad used to work when I looked at it several months ago.
So I'm actually ready to try it but found it does not work now.

works fine in Safari and Firefox.

I cleared all cache and reset to defaults but still produces just a blank page on save. Any ideas how to fix?

console error says: http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/js/app.js:33 Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABSQAAAJ8CAYAAADnFa9pAAAgAElEQVR4XuzdXch1WYIf9JWYSUCUmgqYuRCpaYNEjVJdXhhhopUWomMg1DReOGqgukVw8Ka7ZMDkxp7CG0PA6rrwQoxUNwQmF0J1Q4JRkerWBGbworrxAxGH6kZBE5CaFsHJGG35d589s2fP3uc5H3uvvfbavw0vb9XznrPXWr+1nvM853/Wx+8pLgIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECFQS+D2VylEMAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIEikDSICBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAoJqAQLIatYIIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIEBBIGgMECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECFQTEEhWo1YQAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQIAAAQICSWOAAAECBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIECAAIFqAgLJatQKIkCAAAECB...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
(anonymous) @ http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/js/app.js:33

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Google Chrome has removed support for top-frame navigation, you can see more informations here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM

[JsPDF - Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493234/jspdf-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url/45495974#45495974)