# html2canvas "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL" on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html2canvas

On http://snippet.christopherkade.com I let my user download code snippets, I use `html2canvas` to render and save the console displayed on the screen. This works just fine on Firefox, but Chrome displays this error:

> Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL

When I do the following:

```
// Opens a window with the console to be copied or downloaded
html2canvas(document.getElementsByClassName('console'), {      
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var img = canvas.toDataURL()
    window.open(img);
  }
});
```

Note that Chrome displays a blank page with the error in my console.

The only information I have found is [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM%5B101-125%5D). But it only explains why Google has made this decision and I was not able to see a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493234/jspdf-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url

Answer (score 1):

You can use a blob: URL instead of a data: URL.

```js
b.onclick=async()=>{
  let blob = await new Promise(resolve=>c.toBlob(resolve));
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  // Won't work here, because
  // "the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set."
  window.open(url);
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = '';
  a.click();
};
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
<button id=b>save</button>
```