# Why can I not use Javascript to open dataURIs in a new tab in Chrome while I can in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, tabs, data-uri

My issue is simple. I want to use javascript to open a dynamically generated dataURI inside of a new tab inside a single browser window. The following code does the trick in Firefox ('Hello World' is a toy example. A function returning a string of the generated dataURL will appear in it's place.)

```
 var win = window.open(data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,Hello%20World, '_blank');
 win.focus();
```

In Chrome, this same code will open a totally blank page with the URL space marked `about:blank` instead of the expected URI (as is the case with Firefox).

Either Chrome has this disabled as a security feature of some sort, or Firefox is supporting some aspect of the above code as an experimental feature. Does anyone have a sense of what is going on here? And if so, is there a workaround?

I should add that the Chrome console is not showing any error messages or alerts of any kind.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a Chrome security thing; I would expect Firefox to start behaving that way fairly soon too. Edge also does that I think.

Comment: And yet no console notifications to that effect! In Firefox they explicitly articulated similar issues in the console. https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/

Comment: https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2017/data-url-navigations-on-top-level-window-will-now-be-blocked/ also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsPDF - Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493234/jspdf-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url)