# Base64 PDF not opening on Chromium based browser

Tags: html

I want to display a PDF file encoded in base64 in another tab of the browser when clicking on a link. My problem is that the code works fine in Firefox but is not working on Chromium based browser (tested on Chrome and Edge).

When I say not working, it's not true as it works when you do a right-click and choose the 'open in a new tab'. When simply clicking on the link I have an error message 'Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.' despite the fact that I have no extension on those browsers.

Can someone explain me why it's not working and how can I make it works

Here is an example

```html
<a target="_blank" href="data:application/pdf;base64,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">Test</a>
```

and the result in Chrome

[result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMbv0.png)

Well I don't know why Stackoverflow keeps on delete my greetings but hello everyone...

Comment: Just to be sure, have you run Chrome in safe mode with completely factory settings? You may not have installed any convention extensions like themes or an adblocker, but you still definitely have add-ons, such as decryption codecs.

Comment: Opening Base64 Data URL's is blocked in chrome. Check out the solution in this Stackoverflow post: [JsPDF - Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493234/jspdf-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Just to be sure I reset Chrome to the factory default settings and still have the issue.